# How to change the clicked marker icon using android-maps-utils?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-utils

In my Android project I am using the [*android-maps-utils*](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) library to apply clustering to a bunch of markers on a map view. Whenever a marker is clicked I get notified via [`onClusterItemClick`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/0.3.4/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java#L262) so I can do some action.

```
public interface OnClusterItemClickListener<T extends ClusterItem> {
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(T item);
}
```

Now I would like to let the user know which **marker has been clicked**. The easies visual feedback would be to change the (color of the) marker icon. A icon can be set via the `MarkerOptions` object which can be access within [`onBeforeClusterItemRendered(T item, MarkerOptions markerOptions)`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/0.3.4/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/view/DefaultClusterRenderer.java#L699) such as here:

```
markerOptions.icon(
    BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
        BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
```

If I would have access to the `Marker` object itself such as in [`onMarkerClick (Marker marker)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) I could change the icon via `setIcon`.

How can I change the clicked marker icon?

---

#### Related

- [How to highlight the selected cluster item?](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/174)
- [Android Google Map V2: How to change previous clicked marker's icon when clicked on another marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193902/android-google-map-v2-how-to-change-previous-clicked-markers-icon-when-clicked)

Answer (score 15):

I noticed that the `DefaultClusterRenderer` provides methods to retrieve the `Marker` object associated with a `ClusterItem`. Since I use a custom renderer anyways I was able to access the desired `Marker` object as shown here:

```
mSelectedMarker = mCustomClusterItemRenderer.getMarker(mSelectedClusterItem);
```

This allows me to change the icon within `onClusterItemClick()`:

```
private void updateSelectedMarker() {
    if (mSelectedMarker != null) {
        mSelectedMarker.setIcon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
                        BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how did you undo the update after you clicked on another item?

Comment: It's a while ago. I would think you need to reset the formerly selected marker before or just iterate all markers.

Comment: To avoid iterating over markers, I remembered the last selected marker and just undid the changes to the last marker before updateing the next one. Thanks

Comment: I just did this, but the icon doesn't change. Do you guys call mClusterManager.cluster()?

Comment: @KasparTr how did you remember the last selected marker ?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @JJD, I wrote the same in Kotlin.

```
private var selectedBitmap: BitmapDescriptor? = null
private var unselectedBitmap: BitmapDescriptor? = null
private var lastMarker: Marker? = null
private var clusterManager: ClusterManager<StationClusterItem>? = null

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap

    clusterManager = ClusterManager(context!!, googleMap)
    val clusterRenderer = MarkerClusterRenderer(context!!, googleMap, clusterManager!!,
        unselectedBitmap!!)
    clusterManager!!.renderer = clusterRenderer
    // Add your items to the ClusterManager here with clusterManager?.addItem().
    // Better is in background thread.
    val boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.Builder()
    ...

    clusterManager!!.cluster()
    // Add this listener to make ClusterManager correctly zoom clusters and markers.
    googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager)

    // This method is needed to use setOnClusterItemClickListener.
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager)
    clusterManager!!.setOnClusterItemClickListener { item ->
        lastMarker?.setIcon(unselectedBitmap)
        lastMarker = clusterRenderer.getMarker(item) // Here we access a selected marker.
        lastMarker?.setIcon(selectedBitmap)
        // false - to show info window. See GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.
        // true - to hide info window.
        false
    }
}

class MarkerClusterRenderer(
    val context: Context,
    val map: GoogleMap,
    clusterManager: ClusterManager<StationClusterItem>,
    private val markerBitmap: BitmapDescriptor
) : DefaultClusterRenderer<StationClusterItem>(context, map, clusterManager) {

    init {
        minClusterSize = 1 // 2, 3 or more, as you wish.
    }    

    override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: StationClusterItem?,
                                             markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions)
        markerOptions?.icon(markerBitmap)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I got an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmanaged descriptor` when clicked markers (in a line `lastMarker?.setIcon(unselectedBitmap)`).

After studying [IllegalArgumentException: Unmanaged descriptor using gms.maps.model.Marker.setIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902478/illegalargumentexception-unmanaged-descriptor-using-gms-maps-model-marker-setic) I rewrote that listener:

```
private var selectedItem: StationClusterItem? = null

    clusterManager!!.setOnClusterItemClickListener { item ->
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            // Set here a reference to a previous marker.
            // We save a reference to a previous item, not to a marker.
            val lastMarker = clusterRenderer.getMarker(selectedItem)
            lastMarker?.setIcon(unselectedBitmap)
        }
        selectedItem = item
        // Now get a reference to a selected marker.
        val newMarker = clusterRenderer.getMarker(item)
        newMarker?.setIcon(selectedBitmap)
        false
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for notice `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: @Vlad, thanks! Also I understood, that `false` in `setOnClusterItemClickListener` affects on info window, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60833015/2914140.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer doesn't work correctly for me if a marker became unselected programmatically for a random reason (none is selected).

I added this code to the `DefaultClusterRenderer` inheritor

```
init {
    viewModel.selectedItem.observeForever {
        if (it == null) {
            clusterManager.cluster()
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to destroy it after this renderer lifecycle ends. And actually, it's better to use outside of the renderer. I use it in my `Activity`

```
private fun onMapClickListener(){
    if (viewModel.selectedItem.value != null) clusterManager.cluster()
}
```

And the default icon changing code (I'm simply switching icon color here):

```
override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: ClusterMarker, markerOptions: MarkerOptions) {
    markerOptions.icon(getMarkerColor(item))
}

override fun onClusterItemUpdated(item: ClusterMarker, marker: Marker) {
    marker.setIcon(getMarkerColor(item))
}

private fun getMarkerColor(item: ClusterMarker): BitmapDescriptor {
    val color = if (item.id == viewModel.selectedItem.value?.id) BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE
    else item.getColor()
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(color)
```