# How to create bottom window like this and when the marker is clicked or moved the window is also moved or vice versa in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I want this: when the user swipes the bottom window, the corresponding marker highlights, or when a marker is clicked, the corresponding window should be shown

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a collection of buildings.
2. Create a RecyclerView with an adapter. The adapter must be filled with the collection of buildings.
3. Draw Google Map.
4. Add all pins over the map based on the collection of buildings.
5. Add scroll listener to the RecyclerView so that you know current position. You can use `LinearSnapHelper` for snapping items. When a new item becomes active, deselect last pin on the map and select a new one.
6. Add touch listener for a pin.

Comment: thanks i will try. and can you answer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211784/i-want-to-know-exact-way-to-draw-outline-of-searched-area-in-google-map-in-andro

Comment: @Kora69, sorry, but I don't know.

Comment: i have implemented as you said when a marker is selected then i able to move the recycle view item in center position but i can't get this that  when i move the recycle view child then the corresponding marker is selected?

Comment: @Kora69, you can create a new question in SO. I thought it was possible to draw a corresponding marker with large icon and previuos - with small.

Comment: @Kora69, note that referencing a marker outside of screen area (when it is invisible) may throw an exception. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53829888/2914140.